# Linux: developement environment for testing already installed application

Tags: linux, git, build, development, work-environment

I have cloned repository with git, that I would like to modify and test. However I have already installed this application via apt-get and I wouldn't like to make conflicts. What are good practices to do that ?

Comment: It depends from the application itself. Usually there are settings available via `./configure` or _Makefile_ (different `make` and `make install`) in order to install it only for the current user (you) in a separate path (probably below your home). Check it, read the `README`... Usually without root access (sudo make install) you should not corrupt the system. Last but not least you can set up a Virtual machine to work on it protecting your main system.

Comment: it's a KDE app (okular). The KDE dev team is advising to install their developer package in order to build KDE applications. I am using cinnamon instead of KDE, so I would prefer for the moment something like a virtual environment, but I am not sure to know how to do this.

Comment: OK I found this tutorial in order to build kde on virtual machine: https://techbase.kde.org/Getting_Started/Build/KDE4/on_virtual_machines, but it seems to be quite a heavy solution. Any alternative ?

Comment: Download a pre-installed [Iso image](http://virtualboxes.org/images/), maybe kubuntu one, and add the packages you need after via `apt-get update`, `apt-get ugrade`, `apt-get install whatever_I_need-dev`... At the end you will have your testing machine (even more than one if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set up a docker (https://www.docker.com/) container to test the git version of your application ?

It seems there is existing container for developping kde application : 
https://github.com/Wenzel/docker-kdesrc-build

It should fit your needs.